# A Haskell hash implementation that does not live in the IO monad

Tags: data-structures, haskell, hashtable

I am looking for a data structure that works a bit like `Data.HashTable` but that is not encumbered by the IO monad.  At the moment, I am using [(key,val)].  I would like a structure that is O(log n) where n is the number of key value pairs.

The structure gets built infrequently compared to how often it must be read, and when it is built, I have all the key value pairs available at the same time.  The keys are `String`s if that makes a difference.

It would also be nice to know at what size it is worth moving away from [(key,val)].

Comment: FWIW, I would suggest that you never use `[(key,val)]`.  The interface to `Data.Map` is much more complete, and performance will be markedly better for all but the very smallest collections (maybe < 10 items?)

Comment: John L.  I inherited this structure form "Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 hours."

Comment: John F. Miller: It sometimes comes up because there are prelude functions for dealing with it (e.g. `lookup`), and it can be very convenient.  I always seem to end up with long function compositions with lots of `fst`s and `snd`s, though, which is much more readable with a proper `Map` interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might consider:

- [Data.Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Map.html)

or alternatively,

- [Data.HashMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap)

The former is the standard container for storing and looking up elements by keys in Haskell. The latter is a new library specifically optimized for hashing keys.

Johan Tibell's recent talk, *[Faster persistent data structures through hashing](http://johantibell.com/files/galois-2011.pdf)* gives an overview, while Milan Straka's [recent Haskell Symposium paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/containers/containers.pdf) specifically outlines the `Data.Map` structure and the hashmap package.

Answer (score 3):

If you have all the key-value pairs up front you might want to consider a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash).

Benchmarking will tell you when to switch from a simple list.